# Python hangman, when checking letter it always results as wrong

Tags: python

I am learning Python recently and I am trying to make a hangman game. I followed the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFvSb7cb_Us and modified the code to my liking. However when trying to see if the player put in the correct letter it always results as wrong. I do notice that is because I did not make a way for it to check every letter but every attempt I made to do that ends in a error. Can anyone please help me?

also excuse me if I asked my question in the wrong way, I am new here on stackoverflow.

This is the part that checks for the letter:

```
            lengthWordToGuess = len(randomWord)
        amountWrong = 0
        currentGuess = 0
        currentLettersGuessed = []
        currentLettersRight = 0

        while(amountWrong != 6 and currentLettersRight != lengthWordToGuess):
            print("\nLetters guessed so far: ")
            for letter in currentLettersGuessed:
                print(letter, end=" ")
            letterGuessed = input("\nGuess a letter")
            #guessed right
            if(randomWord[currentGuess] == letterGuessed):
                hangmanVisualPrint(amountWrong)
                currentGuess += 1
                currentLettersGuessed.append(letterGuessed)
                currentLettersRight = giveWord(currentLettersGuessed)
            #guessed wrong
            else:
                amountWrong += 1
                currentLettersGuessed.append(letterGuessed)
                
                hangmanVisualPrint(amountWrong)
                
                currentLettersRight = giveWord(currentLettersGuessed)
```

Comment: You are just checking whether they guessed the FIRST letter.  Surely you want `if letterGuessed in randomWord:` here.

Comment: while it looks like you can do if-checks in parenthesis like you are doing, that is a very non-standard way of writing it. much more conventional in python is to write it as `if a == b:` rather than `if(a==b):`.

Comment: Hey Tim Roberts, yes you are correct! another user, Aleks4920 said the same. I did that and it worked like a charm! Thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: Hi, Scotscotmcc, I did not know that. I will keep it in mind! I am used to C# since if that makes sense. been my main language for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no worries I am quite new too. so python has a cool feature where you can check if a variable is in a list using the `in` keyword [link](https://appdividend.com/2022/05/30/python-list-contains/#:%7E:text=Checking%20if%20the%20item%20exists,not%2C%20then%20it%20returns%20False.). So you can rewrite your code to check `if(letterGussed in correctLetters)` where `correctLetters` can either be the full word or a list of chars. You can check before this for `if(letterGuessed in alreadyGuessed)` and throw a response so they can guess the same letter twice. You can also do this with loops where you check every letter in a list or string.

Comment: omg you know, I already used the in keyword several times yet I did not try it on here! It actually was the answer. I wrote it in, tried a few games. both winning and losing and everything works as it should. Thanks for your help and fast response. I see that we work with a score system on stackoverflow. How can I make sure that you get a good feedback?

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to hear it worked. You have accepted my answer which will give me points but if you upvote that would be greatly apricated. Cheers!

Comment: your comment just so happen to give me enough points to upvote it :P
I just did that, thanks again for your help and have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Please show us the error code from the console. That is usually a good indicator as to which line we should be looking at.

Next why don't you upload all of your code? It may make more sense that way.

Then, use the print("") statement everywhere and visualize where your code is going wrong. I typically put a print() right before my IF statements.

Lastly, Make sure the data types from input() and the randomWord[currentGuess] are the same. For example, the int 5 may not always equal the char '5' or the string '5'.

One more thing, when it come's to new programmers, they tend to struggle with the index of strings. Perhaps you're checking the the wrong letter within 'example' as you could be comparing the 'x' but the input() was given 'e'.

Comment: Yeah I should have done that. But frustration hit me and I was making and deleting changes left and right. I should keep track of it. Sorry for not doing so.

also I did not upload the other part of the code because all the info there is not connected to what is happening in the part I showed

Nonetheless, thanks for your help! I tried the other solution that was given.  But kudos for the fast response!